# ANDROID: Reposition view components in layout for multi window support

Tags: android, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat

I have a layout with numerous Imageviews and Textviews organised in a nested Linear Layouts. Now I need to provide support for multi window
and I have been facing problem when the window size changes. The views goes out of visibility. I don't want to add a scroll view.

Options I considered:
1. Providing different layout (same name as the layout) for different window sizes. (approx. 50%, 75%, 30%)
2. Make the layout a constraint layout - (I don't know if this works for all resizing of multi window)

Which option should I consider and please guide me through the option suggested.

Thanks in advance.

Update : I am adding screen screenshot of evernote app with minimum and max height in multi window resize.

[Min Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpx8O.png)
[Max Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNbvV.png)

Comment: This is not unique to multi-window. You will run into this same issue when dealing with devices with very small screens, even without multi-window. We cannot recommend particular tactics, as we have no idea what your UI is. In general, this is no different than any other screen size/orientation issue: aim for flexible layouts, and offer alternative implementations for different screen sizes/orientations (e.g., `res/layout-w400dp/`) when you need to switch rules for a new range of sizes.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added two images of Evernote app to explain the different min and max height cases, where the layout is organised diffrently

Comment: Use the `-h` resource set qualifier (e.g., `res/layout-h200dp/`) to switch into a different layout when the height reaches a certain value.

Comment: @CommonsWare Will the height not vary for different devices, and when I tried like this, even when the screen height reached the specified height, layout was not changed, the old one remained.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you.. Things worked... Now got a clarity on this...